# Cluster Analysis on a Stratified Random Sample

Tags: clustering, sampling, stratification

I have a set $A$ that consists of 5 million objects. Each object has a color, size and cost. I'd like to do a cluster analysis, e.g. K-means, on cost. However, it is computationally not feasible to use all 5 million objects to do the analysis.

I have 2 options:

Option 1: Someone else performed a stratified random sample of the set $A$ on color and size. I can take that sample and do my cluster analysis.

Option 2: Perform a simple random sample of size $k$ on the entire set $A$ and then do my cluster analysis on the simple random sample.

My question is from a statistical standpoint, i.e. bias, consistency, etc. is their a preference between options 1 and 2? In other words, is expected that I should get different results from the two options. If I cluster into 2 groups, perhaps with option 1 I'll get $10$ as the dividing point between the clusters and with option 2, I'll get $40$ as the dividing point.

Answer (score 1):

Stratified random sampling should give you better performance in accuracy.  There is no way of knowing how much better without seeing your data.  The following table, from [Chapter 5, "Choosing The Type of Probability Sampling"](https://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/40803_5.pdf), is a good summary of comparing the two options (i.e. simple random sampling versus stratified sampling):

[image]